# PyMongo getting only the highest value of a string element

Tags: python, mongodb

i am running a python Application with Mongo DB Backend.

For an EOS Blockchain Query i need to find out the highest Value for an Attribute called eosTimestamp (String)

I created this code:

```
    def getLastEOSTimestampProperty(client,db):
    mydb = client[db]
    collection = mydb["properties"]
    ensure_index(collection,[('eosTimestamp',-1)])
    filter={}
    project={
    'eosTimestamp': 1
        }
    sort=list({
        'eosTimestamp': -1
    }.items()) 
    result = list(client[db][collection].find(
            filter=filter,
            projection=project,
            sort=sort
        ).limit(1))
    maxtimestamp=result[0]['eosTimestamp']
        #return(maxblocknum)
    return str(maxtimestamp)
```

When i run this code i get the following Error Message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\projects\UplandDB\worker.py", line 408, in <module>
    print(getLastEOSTimestampProperty(client,db))
  File "c:\projects\UplandDB\worker.py", line 387, in getLastEOSTimestampProperty
    result = list(client[db][collection].find(
  File "C:\projects\UplandDB\.venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\database.py", line 237, in __getitem__
    return Collection(self, name)
  File "C:\projects\UplandDB\.venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 212, in __init__
    raise TypeError("name must be an instance of str")
TypeError: name must be an instance of str
```

Do You have any hints what i made wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't the sort be the same type as the projection?

Comment: Instead of `sort=list({'eosTimestamp': -1 }.items())`, does `sort = [('eosTimestamp', -1)]` work for you?